# view is not updatable because the primary key of tables is not included in the union result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic view which updates daily, something like this. And it gets modified with last 4 days of tables. I made a change to update datatype of a column which is part of primary key.

Now current table and older tables has mismatch.

For example now the `dbo.Agg20240131` table has changed datatype which is part of primary key

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.Aggupdate 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS   
    SELECT 
        exchange, symbol, timeslice, condition, price, size, 
        volume, sequenceno, totalValue   
    FROM 
        dbo.[Agg20240128]   
    
    UNION ALL    
  
    SELECT 
        exchange, symbol, timeslice, condition, price, size, 
        volume, sequenceno, totalValue   
    FROM 
        dbo.[Agg20240129]   

    UNION ALL    

    SELECT 
        exchange, symbol, timeslice, condition, price, size,
        volume, sequenceno, totalValue   
    FROM 
        dbo.[Agg20240130]   

    UNION ALL    

    SELECT 
        exchange, symbol, timeslice, condition, price, size,
        volume, sequenceno, totalValue   
    FROM 
        dbo.[Agg20240131]
```

Now I am getting this SQL error when trying to insert new rows into the `dbo.AggUpdate` view

> Msg 4444, Level 16, State 10, Line 29
> UNION ALL view 'dbo.AggUpdate' is not updatable because the primary key of table '[dbo].[Agg20240128]' is not included in the union result.

Do we have any other solution instead of updating the datatype of older tables also?

Comment: The problem is the design, not the view. Don't have a table for each day, have a **column** that denotes the day.

Comment: Agree with @ThomA, but also, what stops you from changing the datatype in all tables?

Comment: I haven't seen partitioned views in a *long* time. Almost always these days using the partitioned *tables* functionality is much to be preferred.

Comment: RE "Do we have any other solution instead of updating the datatype of older tables also?" - yes, but it is worth than updating data types of other tables - INSTEAD OF Triggers